# How do you hardware accelerate window scrolling on iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, css

I want to automatically scroll smoothly to a spot on the page. So I wrote a poller that inches closer and closer to that spot. It runs fine on a desktop computer, but it only runs fine on iOS when the page is very simple. If I have some moderate DOM structuring and CSS, the scrolling becomes extremely slow. Is there any way to hardware accelerate this scrolling on iOS?

```
new PeriodicalExecuter(
    function(poller) {
        if (window.scrollY < 999) {
            window.scrollTo(0, window.scrollY + 1);
        } else {
            poller.stop();
        }
    },
    0
);
```

This is using [Prototype JS](http://prototypejs.org/) . [PeriodicalExecuter](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/language/PeriodicalExecuter/) is basically a wrapper around [window.setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout). By using a timeout of 0, I'm requesting that my block of code runs whenever the CPU is free.

Answer (score 1):

What about using:

CSS property: -webkit-touch-callout
+
Overflow: auto

With this combination you can have an scroll pretty fast

Comment: Can you go into more detail? From my readings `-webkit-touch-callout` is disables the default callout shown in iOS when you touch and hold a touch target. How is this related to scrolling?

Comment: Sorry, you were right, I was checking in my code...You should try this (please let me know if this works for you) :    overflow: auto;
 -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;

Comment: Where do I put `-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;`? The Javascript `window` is being scrolled. `window` is not a tag that CSS can target.

Comment: I would need a little bit more info. Can you tell me about the Html structure, and the element you want to be scrolled?

Answer (score 0):

I believe `-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;` goes on the body element.